# Serving static html page in wordpress using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress installed in a root folder and a landing.html file which I want to be a front page for my blog. My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I add `DirectoryIndex landing.html` after `RewriteBase /` line `landing.html` serves as a front page but `index.php` redirects to it as well.

Comment: And yes I tried the standart wordpress approach but the template's css keeps ruining my page and links to scripts and images get broken.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to`DirectoryIndex` try this rule **just below `RewriteBase` line**:

```
DirectoryIndex landing.html index.php

RewriteRule ^$ /landing.html [L]
```

Most likely you can do this via your WP theme also.

Probably your WP permalink setting also needs to change accordingly.

Comment: Still index.php redirects to landing.html

Comment: hmm see updated answer. If it doesn't work I will try o play with WP on my localhost.